# Do the $|$ around $|\langle u,v\rangle|$ refer to absolute value in the inner product version of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, absolute-value, convention

The full inequality is: 
$|\langle u,v\rangle| \leq ||u||    ||v||$

I understand that $||$ around the vectors $u$ and $v$ signifies the taking of their norm, but what do the single | around $\langle u,v\rangle$ mean?

Comment: Yes, it's absolute value.

Comment: Note that in LaTeX, $\|a\|$ (`\| a \|`) should be used over $||a||$ (`|| a ||`) when typesetting vector norms. Compare the readability of $\| v \| \|u \| $ vs. $||u||||v||$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is absolute value.  Note that $\langle u, v \rangle$ is a scalar.  In a real vector space, this is a real number, and you are taking its absolute value in the usual way.  In a complex vector space, it's a complex number, and you are taking its complex modulus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they refer to the absolute value. Since $u$ and $v$ are elements of an inner product space, they require a specific norm. However, $\langle u,v \rangle$ is either a real or complex number, so we use the Euclidean norm.